# prevent shaft from moving in solidworks

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solidworks

i designed a gearbox with 3 shafts.i wanted to do sth so shafts only have rotating movement and not any other type of movement.i cant find any type of mate that can do that,any suggestions?[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have not yet designed/built the housing (which would constrain it in real life) then you need to add reference geometry (either as a master model - recommended, or inside the assembly) in order to constrain the components.

Answer (score 1):

See the .gif below showing how you might set these mates up. **You need to add another part or a sketch into your assembly with axes in the correct places, and then mate your shafts to be concentric to those axes.** Here I have set the parts coincident to the front plane to also limit their axial movement.

[image: Shaft constraint with master model]

Comment: axial movement isnt the problem.the problem is kind of movement it has according to picture recently added.

Comment: Hi @erfan - I understand your problem, and I have presented the solution in my answer. Can you try and explain to me which part you find unclear and I'll try to present it another way to help you understand?

Comment: Hi,i didnt understand the mates,you say coincidence with front plane solves the problem but it will move the way i said in front plane too,look,i did another thing,i draw a circle in front plane and used the mate cocenteric for shaft and the circle,but when i try to rotate the gear it say its defined and cant be moved...

Comment: I have put the key point in bold. Coincident with front plane fixed *axial* movement in my case, because the master sketch was on the front plane, so this should not be your focus. It is the **concentric constraints to the axes in the master model** that you need, which fixes the position of the shafts, while allowing them to rotate.

Comment: exactly,but when i use concentric constraint the error says the selected component is fully defined it cannot be moved.something like the only way it can move is movement of shafts center.

Comment: @erfan - then you must have some other constraint active, which needs to be removed. I have presented a working solution with a video demonstration in my answer. What constraints do *you* have, that I *don't* have? Beyond you sending me the actual model file that you are using, or setting up a live screenshare for me to look at it, I don't know what more to suggest...?

Comment: N.B. You should merge your gears and shafts into three sub-assemblies, and then set up the mates for those sub assemblies exactly as I have in my post above.

Comment: i know you helped as much as you could,im trying to figure out what is limiting the movement,thanks.